# js replace \n with <br> and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have textarea for input and show-div to show the input:

```
<textarea id="inputtext" style="height:100px"></textarea>

<button id="show">show in div</button>

<div id="showtext">

</div>
```

and my js:

```
$(function(){
 $('#show').on('click',function(){
    var text = $.trim($('#inputtext').val());
    text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />").replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
    $('#showtext').text(text);
 });
});
```

What I want is, if you give:
`a`
`b`
`c`

it should also show in this form. but it is showing now: `a b c`.

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're replacing all line breaks with `<br />` and then immediately replacing all `<br />` back to line breaks, which is kinda baffling.

Comment: I'm confused. What are you actually replacing with what?

Comment: Anyway, you might be interested in a CSS-only solution. http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/2/

Comment: @Juhana That's a cool solution, but why is css even needed? http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/3/

Comment: @edhedges Because `pre` doesn't do the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/4/

Comment: @Juhana nice catch m8. I really like this solution btw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your fiddle to match this: http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#show').on('click',function(){
        var text = $.trim($('#inputtext').val());
        text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
        $('#showtext').html(text);
    });
});
```

What you had was replacing the `\n` with `<br />` and then doing the same in reverse so `<br />` was getting replaced with `\n`. Also you needed to set the html of `#showtext`. Check out the difference of [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in the jQuery docs.

There are also other options (these are from the comment sections of the question):

- CSS-only (for the formatting): http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/2/ (**this is coolest solution IMO**)
- Html-only (for the formatting): http://jsfiddle.net/5gkak/3/ (this one doesn't work for all text!)

Comment: @doniyor no problem if this answer works for ya make sure to accept it so it doesn't show up as unanswered.